# is there a CIS button on graphic calculators (Casio/TI)

Tags: calculator

Is there a cis (CosX + iSinX) Button in CASIO graphic calculators ? if so where its ?
if no is there any turn around for it ?

PS. I got a CASIO fx-9860G

Thanks

Comment: I have the CFX-9850G, awesome calculators! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the instruction manual](http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx9860GSD_9860G_E.pdf):

[image: product of two polar-form complex numbers]

So, entering `2∠30` is equivalent to entering $2\text{ cis }30°$.

Comment: Cheers!!! Thanks alot !

Comment: Plus one for RTFM!

Answer (score 1):

$\text{cis}(x)$ is equal to $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried to put e^i(n) and it returns error on Casio. :(

Comment: Have you turned on complex mode on the calculator? (Set up $\to$ Complex Mode). When does it return an error? In the graph mode?